# Makefile static pattern rule matching issue

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I think there is something kind of basic I am missing about the gnu make (I am using 3.81 if it matters) static pattern rule matching (which apparently someone else did as well where I work because this was discovered as I was trying to fix a rule that had been commented out).  I have tried to simplify my example down to the crux of it (hopefully I haven't' missed anything essential in the real example).

So this appears to work as I'd expect

```
JUNK:=foo bar
BINS:=$(patsubst %,bin/%,$(JUNK))

all : $(BINS)
.PHONY : all

# This works
$(BINS) : bin/% : %
        mkdir -p bin && cp $< $@
```

But this (which is closer to what I found in the real Makefile) does not

```
JUNK:=foo bar
BINS:=$(patsubst %,bin/%,$(JUNK))

all : $(BINS)
.PHONY : all

# This doesn't work
$(JUNK) : bin/% : %
       mkdir -p bin && cp $< $@

# This doesn't work either
#bin/$(JUNK) : bin/% : %
#       mkdir -p bin && cp $< $@
```

Based on my understanding of what should be happening in both cases I would have expected that both Makefiles would behave exactly the same; however, only the first one behaves as I expected (i.e., properly copies the files to bin) and the second gives the following output

```
Makefile:12: target `foo' doesn't match the target pattern
Makefile:12: target `bar' doesn't match the target pattern
make: *** No rule to make target `bin/foo', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

What is more confusing is there are nearly identical other static pattern rules in the make file I was examining that were working.

So I obviously know how to "work around" the issue if need be but I'd like to understand why the second (and the commented out portion in the second code block as well) do not do what I expect them to.

Thanks in advance for any help/insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one doesn't work because, after expanding the `JUNK` variable, make sees this:

```
foo bar : bin/% : %
```

The way static pattern rules work is that the first pattern (the target pattern) *must* match each word in the list of targets.  That tells make which part of the target name is the stem (the part that matches the `%`).  If the target pattern doesn't match, make doesn't know what the stem is.  The pattern `bin/%` does not match the text `foo`, (there is no `bin/` in the text `foo`) so you get the error you see.

The second one doesn't work because the result of exanding the `JUNK` variable in this example (`bin/$(JUNK) : bin/% : %`) looks like this:

```
bin/foo bar : bin/% : %
```

Here, `bin/foo` matches the pattern, but `bar` doesn't match and so you get the same error as you did in the previous one.

To make it work you must have `bin/` prepended to *every* target, not just the first target, hence the use of `patsubst` (or, `addprefix` would work as well).